# Two values to count in left outer join to same table

Tags: sql-server-2008

two tables `(family_table)` and `(children_table)` that are related by `family_id` , 
How do you count children that have `state 'a'` and children that have `state 'b'` to each family via one query?

I tried query but the result of count of `children_state 'b'` and count of `children_state 'a'` is wrong , and i don't know where is the problem , my query is :

```
select f.family_id ,
count(c.family_id) as [B children Count] ,
count(cp.family_id) as [A children Count]
FROM Family_table as f left outer join children_table as c
on c.family_id = f.family_id and c.children_state = 'B' left outer join children_table as cp
on cp.family_id = f.family_id and c.children_state = 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want:

```
select f.family_id ,
       SUM(CASE c.children_state WHEN 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [B children Count] ,
       SUM(CASE c.children_state WHEN 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as [A children Count]
       SUM(CASE WHEN c.children_state <> 'd' and c.children_state <> 'e' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Some other count]
FROM Family_table as f 
join children_table as c
on c.family_id = f.family_id
GROUP BY f.family_id
```

It works by using a sum, and then within that sum applying the condition you are interested in for the particular count.  That way you can have multiple different 'counts' from the one join

If you have other conditions, then just add additional SUM columns, using different CASE statements

Comment: can i add conditions to  'when' word example : when 'B' and children_state <> 'd' and children_state <> 'e' ??

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand - a child can't be B and <> 'd' at the same time...  I've added an example of a more complex condition to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try a group by

*The sql below is not verified as I don't have access to sqlserver at work*

```
select f.family_id , c.children_state, count(c.children_state) 
FROM Family_table as f left outer join children_table as c 
on c.family_id = f.family_id 
and c.children_state in ('A','B')
group by f.family_id , c.children_state
```

Comment: ok .. what if i want count children that have state 'A' and children that have not state 'A' or 'c' ??

Comment: @user3038625  Your constraints against c.children_state can be added before the group by. The key part is that the group by will do the count for you once the constraints have been satisfied.   e.g.  replace and c.children_state in ('A','B') with and c.children_state in ('A','B') or ( c.children_state = 'C' and c.children_state != 'A')

Comment: I'll have to spin up my sqlserver at home tonight and figure out exact syntax. sorry.

Comment: the syntax is right ..but the result of 2 count column is equal